# What does the Mermaid Queen's title mean?

Tags: ice-fantasy

The queen of the Mermaid Clan in *Ice Fantasy* is frequently (in the English subtitles) called either Predor Mermaid or Mermaid Saint. The first title I've seen only in *[Star Wars](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Predor)*, and I can't find evidence that it's a real-world title. The latter seems a bit odd.

What term or terms do these correspond to in Mandarin? What do they really indicate about the position of the Mermaid Clan ruler?

Comment: A quick play with google translate suggests that the closest translation of 人鱼圣尊 is "the holy mermaid" or "respected holy mermaid" (e.g. Mermaid Saint). Predor may be a mistranslation of [Praetor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praetor), a high-ranking official in the Roman Army.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate the original 人鱼圣尊 character by character, the first two (*Rényú*, as transliterated by Google) correspond to "fish people," which is apparently a standard form used to denote "mermaids."  The last two characters (*shèng* and *zūn*), mean something like "holy" and "respected," and so "saint," in the sense of "respected for holiness" is not a terrible translation.*

For the title "Mermaid Saint" to be idiomatic in English, it would need a definite article, but "the Mermaid Saint," seems fine for expressing the required meaning.  On the other hand, "predor" is unknown to the *Oxford English Dictionary*; it does not mean anything in English.  (In a comment, Valorum suggested it might have been meant to be "praetor," which is possible, although there is no holiness aspect of that title; it just means a high elected magistrate, both in its original Latin context as well as occasional usage in English.)

*Although I got the transliterations from Google Translate, I ran the whole reading by Chinese friend, and he confirmed it.